# Is it possible to get the Watson agent version associated with a given workspace_id?

Tags: ibm-watson

I am using v1 of the Watson API. It's possible I am missing something in the [documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1), but I can't see to figure out how to determine the version of an agent for a given `workspace_id`.

I'm interested in doing this so that I can log the Watson response server-side, with the associated agent version, which changes as the agent evolves and new content is added.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the concept of Watson assistant versions is only supported by the Watson V2 API. Additionally, that API does not presently expose the current version of the assistant being called.